# Getting a mysterious type conversion when using the get function from Maya API class MArgList

Tags: c++, api, plugins, maya

I am using the MArgList class from the Maya API to retrieve arguments entered in the Maya command line. According to the class reference MArgList::get should be able to take an int or double as its second argument but it seems to be expecting a bool only and so throws a conversion error during compiling. The following is the code section and the errors generated. Any thoughts on what might be causing this would be much appreciated. The code was typed straight out of a tutorial on Maya plugin development, so it is a mystery why it is not working.

```
const int nPosts = 5;
const double radius = 0.5;
const double height = 5.0;

unsigned index;
index = args.flagIndex( "n", "number" );
if( MArgList::kInvalidArgIndex != index )
    args.get( index + 1, nPosts );

unsigned index;
index = args.flagIndex( "r", "radius" );
if( MArgList::kInvalidArgIndex != index )
    args.get( index + 1, radius );

unsigned index;
index = args.flagIndex( "h", "height" );
if( MArgList::kInvalidArgIndex != index )
    args.get( index + 1, height );


1>Posts1Cmd.cpp(37): error C2664: 'MStatus MArgList::get(unsigned int,bool &) const' :               cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const int' to 'bool &'
1>Posts1Cmd.cpp(39): error C2086: 'unsigned int index' : redefinition
1>          Posts1Cmd.cpp(34) : see declaration of 'index'
1>Posts1Cmd.cpp(42): error C2664: 'MStatus MArgList::get(unsigned int,bool &) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const double' to 'bool &'
1>Posts1Cmd.cpp(44): error C2086: 'unsigned int index' : redefinition
1>          Posts1Cmd.cpp(34) : see declaration of 'index'
1>Posts1Cmd.cpp(47): error C2664: 'MStatus MArgList::get(unsigned int,bool &) const' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const double' to 'bool &'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to get new values from the `get` function, you cannot have the target variables `const`.

Try

```
int nPosts = 5;
double radius = 0.5;
double height = 5.0;
```

Also, you should not declare a new `index` variable for each call. Just declare it once and reuse it.